# Get the result of a php process (with php), that includes a die command

Tags: php, file, include, return, die

Initial Outline

I am using php to write a custom file serving tool for a project i am working on. The tool works well so far, but i have bumped into an odd situation when serving php files.

My initial file, server.php is designed to take a file request and serve the file with correct headers and cache controls etc.

Server.php uses file commands to get the contents of flat files like images and serve them echo print style.

Server.php currently uses include (with output buffering) to get the contents of php files to serve. This works well until the including file contains a die command.

I have experimented using return, instead of die to terminate the process. But it fails to perform the job of die if the included file, includes further files.

---

So in a nutshell, i have got one PHP file "server.php", this includes another php file. I want to get its processed output as if it was an independent flat file. I do not care about the variables being moved into the global scope, I just want the output. Any ideas?

Thanks Guys

---

**EDIT**

server.php

```
<?php
echo 'File start'."<br>\n";
        ob_start();
        include("file.php");
echo    ob_get_clean();
echo 'File end'."<br>\n";
?>
```

file.php

```
<?php
echo 'I am expecting to get this data.'."<br>\n";
die;
echo 'I am not expecting to get this data.'."<br>\n";
?>
```

I hoping to get a result that roughly looks like.

File start
I am expecting to get this data.
File end

What i get is a result that looks like.

File start
I am expecting to get this data.

If i use a return instead of a die, i get the expected result. But that dosnt stop people using die and breaking my program. Hopefully my edit better explains the problem. Cheers again guys.

Comment: Are you saying that you're running other people's code, which may or may not have a call to `die` in it, and you have no control over it? That sounds like a very very bad idea. What are you doing this for?

Comment: I understand what your saying, and not that i'm running other peoples code. But certainly running code that could contain a die. If i can make it work, i could eventually run other peoples code.

I am actually using server.php as an experiment in managing file requests to a web server. I have a simple htaccess rule that forwards all requests to server.php.

Comment: At the moment i have wrote a class that emulates the file targeting system and url rewrite engine. Which once processed attempts to serve the file.

This is working very well at the moment, and does resolve a php webpage using include and output buffering at the moment. But if said page contains a die, the remaining part of my program, which records the payloads, ceases to run.

Comment: The issue, then, is that the page contains a `die`. A quick google search of why `die` is bad can give quite a few reasons. The main point, however, is that it's a poor and lazy way of controlling the flow of code. You should only really HAVE to `die` if something goes wrong - and in those cases, you should really favour throwing an exception, as that can be dealt with.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and honesty, and so far you have been spot on. At the moment requests that resolve a php with a die, just have the recorded payloads as "terminated early". Which is the same when i throw an error, unless its a non breaking one. But again thank you, i may have to settle with looking at "terminated early".

Comment: With respect pudge, ill leave the question open a little while longer before i press answered. Just incase someone can shed more light.

Answer (score 0):

Using `include` will run the other files in the current process. To run them in another process, you can use `exec`, or the `proc_*` functions, or possibly use forking.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php

The choice of which one to use depends entirely on what your requirements.

**EDIT**

To run a php script using the `exec` function, try something along these lines;

```
exec("php $absolutePathToScript", $output, $result);

if ($result !== 0) { //the script did not throw an error
    print_r($output) // will show the output of the command
}
```

Comment: Without being too stupid, ive had a peek at the above links and they seem abit beyond my abilities. My command line knowledge is poor.

Is their a more direct way to get the result of the process?

Comment: From what I can tell of your description, this isn't a case of "getting the result of a process" -> you aren't actually creating another process at the moment, merely running other code in your current process. I can try to give an example of running a php file using exec in my answer.

Comment: You were right i was not clear... I'm happy to have it included into the current process, instead of starting another. But i would like "the result of that part of the process" As a string to print.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to get content of PHP file, because include and require will execute PHP code from included file